# How to add up numbers in a php string?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, addition

I have a PHP string that contains numbers. Is there a way to add up all the numbers in a string?

For example: I have a string called $soc_count. That string outputs the following:

1 1

Is there a way to add up all the numbers in a string?

My code:

```
<?php $soc_count = [];$soc_count = (get_row_layout() == 'irl_today_social_media');?>
<?php echo $soc_count;?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming numbers are positive integers and string is not empty, you can try this:

```
eval('$sum = ' . trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', "+0+", $soc_count), '+') . ';');

echo $sum;
```

Comment: Yikes! I would never use `eval()` for a task that could be done ANY other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode` on your string of numbers, and then sum up the array:

```
$soc_count = "1 1";
$nums = explode(" ", $soc_count);
$total = array_sum($nums);
echo $total;
```

For a more general solution, which would cover a string of any type having numbers in it, we can try using `preg_match_all`:

```
$soc_count = "1 quick brown fox jumped over 1 lazy dog.";
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $soc_count, $matches);
$nums = $matches[0];
$total = array_sum($nums);
echo $total;
```

Comment: Didn't add up. Still shows up as 1 1. The string is dynamic

Comment: My answers definitely work for the sample string you showed us.  If there be a problem with my answer, then state what input data you are using.

Comment: I did `$soc_count = (get_row_layout() == 'irl_today_social_media');
$nums = explode(" ", $soc_count);
$total = array_sum($nums);
echo $total;` and it shows up as 1 1. When I did the code above, it worked

Comment: [Please check the demo where both versions are working](https://rextester.com/OMB59481).